# Windows Server 2008 Licence Limitations

Tags: licensing, windows-server-2008

I'm about to purchase a copy of Windows Server 2008 (User CAL, 5 CLT)
is IIS Going to be limited to 5 concurrent anonmous internet users?

Comment: While I don't know much about Windows Server licensing, it would be kind of absurd having to buy one license per expected internet user of a web server :)

Comment: true, but better safe than REALLY sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not :)

Answer (score 2):

Nope

[Windows Server 2008 Client Access Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/client-licensing.aspx)

Relevant portion:

> Every user or device that accesses or uses the Windows Server 2008 server software requires the purchase of a Windows Server 2008 Client Access License (Windows Server CAL) **except under the following circumstances**:
>
> - If access to the instances of server software is **only through the Internet without being authenticated** or otherwise individually identified by the server software or through any other means
> - If access is to Windows Web Server 2008
> - If external users are accessing the instances of server software and you have acquired a Windows Server 2008 External Connector license for each server being accessed
> - For up to two devices or users to access your instances of the server software only to administer those instances
> - If you are using Windows Server 2008 solely as a virtualization host (you will still require CALs for your appropriate WS edition)